# Trigger the setinterval after post data is received

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a jQuery $post() to bring data when the page loads. Also I've got a setInterval() to load some other data when the page loads.

```
  $.post('my.php',
    { 
      send:"123"
    },
    function(resp){
      //trigger setInterval now
  });
```

how do I trigger the setinterval after the data is being received?

```
var wait = setInterval(function() {
     //do something
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Do you mean _"call setInterval() now"_, or do you mean _"call the function **passed** to setInterval() now"_?

Comment: @robertklep thanks. To call the function passed to setInterval()

Comment: you can't save any **setInterval** or **setTimeout** in variable.
and about your issue it sounds like you want to execute a function on the **$.post success response**.
on success you can use **setTimeout** function to execute after some time.

Comment: @Yog are you sure that `var wait = setInterval(function() {` this is incorrect?

Comment: @Yog why not can't do `var wait = setInterval()` ?

Comment: bro see, 
var **a** = setInterval();// setInterval is executed!  it saves the setInterval's programmatic counter in variable **a**. which can be useful to remove interval in javascript like, **clearInterval(a)**.
and same for setTimeout

Answer (score 2):

```
function myIntervalFunction() {
  // do something, your interval function
}

// start the general interval working process
setInterval(myIntervalFunction, 1000);

$.post('my.php', { send:"123" },
    function(resp){
        // trigger myIntervalFunction once
        // after the ajax call is finished
        myIntervalFunction();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.post('my.php',
    { 
      send:"123"
    },
    function(resp){
      var wait = setInterval(function() {
     //do something
     }, 1000);
  });
```

Has no reason not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Either declare it inside the response function:

```
$.post('my.php',
{ 
  send:"123"
},
function(resp){
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
   //do something
  }, 1000);
});
```

or make it a function and call it on response:

```
function start_interval () {
    return setInterval(function() {
     //do something
    }, 1000);
}

$.post('my.php',
{ 
  send:"123"
},
function(resp){
  interval = start_interval()
});
```

Comment: `function start_interval`  not appear to have `(){` before `return setInterval(function() {` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("my.php", {send: "123"}, function() {
    var wait = setInterval(function() {
        alert("1 sec");
        clearInterval(wait);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining reference to `setInterval` `interval` function `wait` outside scope of `success` callback of `$.post()` ; call `wait` , optionally passing parameter, within `success` callback of `$.post()`

```
// define reference variable `interval` , set to `0`
var interval = 0;

var wait = function(data) {
  // set `interval` as reference to `setInterval`
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(data)
  }, 1000)
}  

$.post("my.php", {send:"123"}, function(resp) {
      // pass `resp` to `wait`, call `setInterval` , 
      wait(resp);
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pp2rwu8c/